# Autocomplete textbox in qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am new to QT, how to implement autocomplete textbox in qt or is there already solution for that ? I have vector of words. Can somebody give me advice how to do this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at [QCompleter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html).

> The QCompleter class provides completions based on an item model.
>
> You can use QCompleter to provide auto completions in any Qt widget,
> such as QLineEdit and QComboBox. When the user starts typing a word,
> QCompleter suggests possible ways of completing the word, based on a
> word list. The word list is provided as a QAbstractItemModel. (For
> simple applications, where the word list is static, you can pass a
> QStringList to QCompleter's constructor.)

Comment: great, I didn't know this existed. I was looking for something like this for a different purpose. Thanks

Comment: QCompleter is about the most inflexible completer I've worked with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `QComboBox` with its `editable` attribute set to `true.`